# What is this super-fly?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

This fly repeatedly buzzed in my girlfriend’s ear. Eventually got it from it being caught in her hair. I clapped it between my hands. It fell on the floor and twitched a bit as flies sometimes do. It started walking away again. I hit it hard with the side of my fist against the carpet. Still going. I hit it multiple times and it left a blood mark. I went to get some paper to collect it. And it’s walking away again! I pinched it in the paper. Still moving about. It’s now in a jar. I suspect it is actually a forward member of some kind of nation-state engineered nano invasion force.

I have a lot of experience with fly disposal but this thing is actually scarily hard! Also the fact it was ear-buzzing seems very mosquito-like behaviour. But it clearly isn’t a mozzie.

If you are a fly researcher and want the next breakthrough in self-healing psycho DNA give me a shout.

But what is it?

Location Yorkshire UK. Size about 6mm head to tail?

[image: fly]

---

[image: fly]

Comment: Please leave a comment if downvoting (snooze). This is my first question on this site so apologies for my layman’s effort.

Comment: @user338907 Haha no, we have a 2 year old so it’s kind of past that stage.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Links, particularly for images, within a question can age and rot, leaving the question unanswerable and not useful for anyone reading the post. Please make your question self-contained.